# Importing Liferay portlet into Eclipse IDE

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-ide

I haved created a portlet through plugins SDK and wanted to import that into the eclipse ,but it did not imported as it is ,

But after creating the portlet if i give " ant setup-eclipse " then the project get imported into the eclipse .i have searched for this almost 2 days then i found the solution ..

How do i know what all the commands i have in ant . like in the API i will have all the methods where i can see there and get on with my coding work ,how with ant ?
how do i know wat all the commands i need to implement ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how do I find out what targets are available in your ant build file?  Targets like "setup-eclipse" for example?

Comment: may be s ,how do i find out ?

Answer (score 1):

IF you install the [Liferay IDE plugins](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Installation+Guide) it has a wizard for importing existing portlets projects that have previously been created by the plugins SDK.  There is also a wiki page for how to [import existing projects](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Importing+Existing+Projects) into Eclipse after you have Liferay IDE plugins installed.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse there is View for "Ant", just like we have views like "Server", "Console", "Outline", "Package Explorer" etc.

**This is how you can select the View and see Targets:**

1. Windows --> Show view --> Other --> (Type filter text as **Ant**)
2. Now drag your **build.xml** to this View and voila you can see all the commands or targets available for the build file.

Hope this helps.